# Можно ли использовать сторонний dll в своей программе?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, namespace, компоновщик

и если да то как?
Имеется dll, и даже исходный код открыт (можно скомпилировать в vs2010). Dll от игры, в ней есть некая нужная мне функция (отображает список серверов в интернете), к сожалению в SDK этой dll я нашел только .h файлы того что мне нужно, в которых не описано ничего (возможно кто-то своим опытным глазом и сможет мне помочь), поэтому я подумал, а нельзя ли прикрепить в свою программу этот файл и вызвать нужную мне функцию (название я знаю, а вот кода не вижу так как хз где нужный cpp файл). Собственно есть же dll которые подкрепляют и через их namespace вызывают то что нужно.
[Ссылка](http://superpower2.ru/superpower2/SDK1.5.zip) на код

Comment: Для чего они нужны тогда, если нельзя?

Comment: Если вопрос в том, можно ли из c# вызвать c++ функцию, зная ее прототип, то ответ - "да". См. [DllImportAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: не в том вопрос, вопрос как вызвыать ее. ну и дополню что моя программа на cli

Comment: Если это cli, причем тут метка c#? В cli вы можете просто скопировать функцию в свой код из кода библиотеки.

Comment: Вы читали что я написал в теме? К тому же для меня нет проблем перевода кола из c# в cli и наоборот.

Comment: Я читал, но не понял, в чем именно вопрос. Вызвать функцию из DLL - задача довольно простая (тем более, при наличии исходного кода), с чем именно возникают сложности? В  C# для этого используется атрибут DllImport. Вы не знаете как его использовать или как составить объявление конкретной функции (соотвествие типов и т.п.)?

Comment: Почитайте "Импорт функций DLL". А может ещё и как работают ф-ции `LoadLibray` и `GetProcAddress`